Entity Framework Core code-first connection string for multiple repositories
I have my own framework that I've been working on for years. It has an AppSecurity project that handles users, roles, permissions, etc. For it, I created an EF Core code-first DbContext class:
internal class AppSecurityDataContext : DbContext
{
    private string _connectionString = @"Server=mysite.com;Database=TheLastAppIWorkedOn;User Id=abc1;Password=xyx2;";

    public AppSecurityDataContext()
    {
    }

    public AppSecurityDataContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>().HasData
        (
            new UserEntity
            {
                // Properties set here
            }
        );
    }
}

Right now I'm working on a WPF app called Falcon. It has its own DbContext which manages the Falcon DB objects. Right now, the connection string for it is stored in the DbContext class becuase I'm not sure how this is supposed to be done.
private string _connectionString = @"Server=mysite.com;Database=Falcon;User Id=someone;Password=somepwd;";

public FalconDataContext()
{
}

public FalconDataContext(string connectionString)
{
    _connectionString = connectionString;
}

public FalconDataContext(DbContextOptions<FalconDataContext> options) :
    base(options)
{
}

Next week, I could be in another app that needs to use AppSecurity. Herein lies the problem - when I work on other apps that use the AppSecurity project, I have to open its DbContext class, change the connection string, then open Package Manager and rebuild.
So, how can my AppSecurity project get the connection string the other project I'm working?

So, you do not use Dependency Injection? Storing connection string inside DbContext class is bad approach.

The question is based on a bad design. EF is an ORM and neither has nor needs "repositories". A DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work, a higher abstraction than low-level single-entity CRUD classes. You can use the same type in multiple DbContexts (and that's what you should do here). If you follow conventions, or use attributes, you won't have to add any code to the contexts beyond public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;}. As for connections, these should be configured outside the context and passed as parametes. Even the database provider should be passed from the outside

The whole concept of configuration is about being able to keep some parameters out of the code, possibly in a form that can be edited without the need to recompile the application. Net Core has a great support of various configuration sources. You definitely should take a look at that.

You should use the DbContext(DbContextOptions) constructor to pass the provider, connection strings and options from the outside, as most examples show.

Thanks everyone for your replies, however, I'm not sure my question was answered. I need to somehow get the connection string from the Falcon project into the AppSecurity project. Does it get passed in somehow? What does that looks like? Or does the AppSecurity project somehoe "read" it in?
